# Adding a Custom Component in Telerik Reporting - WPF

Tags: telerik, telerik-reporting

Is it possible to add a custom toolbar button component in WPF report viewer or not. 
If possible, how? 
Basically i want to add a refresh button that would reset some controls in the grid. 
Closest i got to it is here by expression blending http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/silverlight-design-time-expression-blend.html but it's not working too.!